# Почему результат SELECT'ов с <= ALL и MIN разный?

Tags: sql, select

Схема БД состоит из четырех таблиц:

```
Product(maker, model, type)  
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)  
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, price, screen)  
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

Задание: Найдите производителей самых дешевых цветных принтеров. Вывести: maker, price

Неправильно:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker, price
FROM printer, product
WHERE printer.model = product.model
AND (color = 'y')
AND price <= ALL (SELECT price
FROM printer WHERE color = 'y')
```

Правильно:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker, price
FROM printer, product
WHERE printer.model = product.model
AND color = 'y'
AND price = (SELECT MIN(price)
FROM printer WHERE color = 'y')
```

Comment: результат отличается только количеством записей?

Comment: А что на sql-ex.ru не отвечают?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, это из-за того, что в столбце `price` может встретиться `NULL`, и тогда оператор `ALL` не вернёт результат, т.к. для данной строки условие `price <= NULL`, естественно, не выполнится.

Например:

```
with my_data (maker, price) as 
(select 'A', 10 from dual
 union
 select 'B', null from dual
 union
 select 'C', 30 from dual)
select * 
  from my_data md1
 where price <= all (select price from my_data);
```

Стоит только заменить `select 'B', null from dual` на `select 'B', 2 from dual` как всё "начинает работать". Функция же `min()` выбирает минимальное значение, и наличие среди них `NULL` не мешает вернуть результат.